# macOS Dictation: Some commands don’t work

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

I am experimenting with Mac OS dictation. The problem is that I can’t get many of the commands listed on https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mh40695/mac to work. In particular I can’t get the `new line` command to work.

Strangely enough every time I tried to say `new line`, what I get is an extra space so I can’t even dictate the words “new line”.

Is there a solution to getting these commands to work? I read somewhere that being in a being in Australia may have an affect on these commands but I don’t know why.

I’m also finding that dictation times out after maybe a minute or so and there’s nothing I can do to get it going longer.

I have tried this in both Big Sur and Monterey (released today).

Comment: Are you saying it in « American English »? :) sorry couldn’t resist…

Comment: Actually, I did try putting on an American accent, but it wasn’t convinced. After your suggestion, I thought I’d see what happens if I set it to US English, but that still didn’t help.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably due to your accent. That's not really nice of Apple...